# iTunesU course with PDFs for personal use

Tags: itunes, pdf, itunes-u

I have a bunch of mp4's and PDF's as a part of a Spanish learning course downloaded off the Internet. I am trying to add the package to my iTunesU library so that it stays better organized and easy to study.

I know a way to add media to iTunes is via the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder. For example, I need to add a video to iTunesU or Home Videos section, I just need to copy it into the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder and iTunes automatically adds it to the Movies library from where one can change it's "Get Info" panel to move it to the appropriate category. Works fine for multimedia, but this method isn't working for PDFs.

I don't want to build a course and publish it to iTunes because I am not the author. I simply want to organize it under the iTunesU section of my iTunes app for strictly personal use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this — courses with additional documentation such as PDFs can't be constructed in this way for personal use only.

---

Additional course materials need to be added to a course using iTunes U Course Manager. You need the iTunes U Course Manager to create such courses — setting the media type in iTunes doesn't work for this.

If you really want to make a course, you can use Course Manager and create a private course:

> **private course**
>   An iTunes U Course Manager course available only to students invited by the instructor (no more than 50 students per course). By default, all courses created in Course Manager are private.

For more information regarding adding course materials to a course using Course Manager, see:

- https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/help/#itu71ED26AD-D083-40D4-8C6E-AB4DB846CA75